# Error - Names attribute not match length of the Vector

Tags: r

I received the below error for the below code, I think it's a formatting issue with the Gender and the job level which we refer to as "N-IC2", etc...but we can't figure it out:

```
Error in names(x) <- value :    'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [4]


#Additionally Requested Crosstabs
GenLev<-aggregate(dat1$JobLev~dat1$Gender,FUN=summary)
GenLev<-as.data.frame(as.matrix((GenLev)))
colnames(GenLev)<-c("Gender","N-IC1","N-IC2","N-IC3","N-MG1","N-MG2","N-MG3")
write.xlsx(GenLev,"C:\\Users\\mvandenplas\\Desktop\\DS21Output4.xlsx",sheetName="GenderXLevel",append = TRUE)
```

Comment: it seems like your GenLev df has only 4 columns but your names vector has 7 items (that is what the error tells us at least but also error messages can be missleading).. can you show the result of head(GenLev) just before the colnames(GenLev) call?

Comment: Perhaps you can type `print(colnames(GenLev))` in your R terminal and paste the output into your question. From what I see, the error message tells you that you want to replace the column names with more elements than you have columns.